# Inheriting from an abstract class and defining an abstract method to be an existing child class's method

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose you have an ABC `base` with a method `compute`, and 2 child classes `child1, child2` with `compute` defined. `child1, child2` only inherit from `base`.

Then suppose you another another class `related` that inherits from `base` as well as some other classes not mentioned here.

`related` needs to define `compute` in this case, but its definition is either the same as `child1`'s or `child2`'s depending on a flag that's passed into `related`'s constructor.

So here's an example of how I currently do it.

```
class related(base, some other classes...):
  def __init__(self, toggle_flag, some other args):
    self.toggle_flag = toggle_flag
    if toggle_flag:
      return child1.__init__(self, some other args)
    else:
      return child2.__init__(self, some other args)


  def compute(self):
    if toggle_flag:
      return child1.compute(self)
    else:
      return child2.compute(self)
```

I don't have much experience writing OOP in Python as I mostly have a C++ background, but this design here looks a bit strange to me. Is there another way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: `related` should probably not be a single class, but two separate subclasses of `child1` and `child2`, respectively. (Instead of passing a boolean flag to instantiate the original `related`, you use the value of that flag to decide whether to instantiate `related1` or `related2`.)

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but `related` isn't used in standalone mode. it's actually inherited by other classes, so we run into the same issue with those classes :(. I think there's a design flaw with the code base I'm working in but it is what it is right now

Comment: I don't think there's enough detail in the current question to suggest an appropriate solution. I agree there's a design flaw, but without seeing the actual design, it's hard to pinpoint how to fix it. You should generally not be using either child's `compute` method as it if were an ordinary function just because you happen to know the body is appropriately defined. (`related` is not an instance of either child, so how do you know it's initialized properly to be used by a child's method?)

Comment: Do the `compute` methods in the child classes need other methods or instance variables of their respective class or from the `base` class (or may need them in the future)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I just edited the OP. In `related`'s constructor, it also calls one of the child's classes constructors depending on the `toggle_flag`, and the child class's constructor initializes any instance variables that are needed. The child class's `compute` method does rely on instance variables but they were initialized in the constructor. There are no other methods in the child class besides `compute`

Comment: The more you keep trying to apply child methods to instances of `related`, the less clear it is why you don't actually inherit. *Why* does `related` have to be a single class (which prevents it from properly inheriting from the correct child class)?

Comment: @chepner Do you mean in your first comment, where you're suggesting to esentially make a `related1` and `related2` that inherits separately from `child1, child2`, resp? That brings us back to my comment in response to that, which is that `related` is also inherited by another class, so we run into the same issue with that other class

Comment: Yes, *those* classes need to be redesigned as well, because`related` shouldn't just be hijacking methods from unrelated classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always consider whether composition may be a better option than inheritance.

(Note: I'm capitalizing the class names -- this is standard Python convention and makes it easy to see what's a class and what's an instance.)

```
class Related(Base, some other classes...):
    def __init__(self, toggle_flag, some other args):
        self.computer = (Child1 if toggle_flag else Child2)(some other args)

    def compute(self):
        return self.computer.compute()
```

In the above example, rather than trying to make our `Related` do a sort of pseudo-inheritance from `Child1` or `Child2` (which is going to pollute our `Related` namespace with all of the private attributes of whatever class we chose -- this could lead to some really fun bugs if there are any name conflicts between those and any other attributes that `Related` might define), we simply create a new instance of one or the other that we'll delegate our `compute` method to.

You could technically even do:

```
class Related(Base, some other classes...):
    def __init__(self, toggle_flag, some other args):
        self.compute = (Child1 if toggle_flag else Child2)(some other args).compute
```

but I would personally prefer the first form.

Comment: I definitely think composition is better here but I'm having a hard time convincing my team to do it because the existing design pattern uses inheritance for this part of the codebase.

Comment: You can still have `Related` inherit from `Base` if you need to -- just don't do the thing of trying to *mimic* inheritance by calling a sibling class's `__init__`.  You're basically already using composition at that point, but by trying to *pretend* you aren't using composition you're just using it in the worst way possible.  If you're *actually* going to use inheritance, then as others have suggested, you should have two `Related` classes that *actually* inherit from `Child1` and `Child2`.  The benefit of composition is that you can have one class that uses the functionality of either.

Comment: Going to have to convince my team to do it :|. However, by using composition, doesn't make inheriting `Base` moot? The only thing it really does is force you to define a `compute` in `related`

Comment: Yes, potentially -- you didn't say whether `Base` has any other properties (aside from the abstract `compute` method) that are important here.  But even if that's all it does, it might still be valuable from a typechecking perspective (i.e. you can pass a `Related` to a function that expects a `Base` and it will be obvious that it implements some kind of `compute`) -- although a more modern approach would be to use a `Protocol` to accomplish the same thing rather than an ABC.

Comment: If it's determined that it's not important for any other reason to have `Related` inherit `Base`, my approach would be to just not do that, *and* not have it define its own `compute`.  Just have that `computer` attribute, and call its `compute` when needed without having an extra wrapper around it.  KISS.

Comment: I'll note -- I am absolutely *not* dogmatic about always doing composition over inheritance.  I think if you have something that works well with inheritance, use it.  But this is very obviously something that is *not* working well with an approach that requires these classes to inherit from each other in this particular way.  Use what works in a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question largely depends on the underlying design in the codebase which (rightfully) you can't explain in a single post.

If *the only reason* why `related` inherits from `base` is so it can have its own `compute`, then chances are that you're better of passing an instance of `base`'s children, so that `related.compute` looks like

```
def compute(self, derived_from_base):
    return derived_from_base.compute(self)
```

or even give `related` `derived_from_base` as a member in the constructor, so that

```
def compute(self):
   return self.derived_from_base.compute(self)
```

However, if the inheritance is more convoluted because `related` needs more functionality inherited from `base`, then you should post a new question addressing the actual *design* as opposed as specific features in Python vs C++.

Comment: "instance of `base`? Is this a typo since `base` is an abstract class and therefore can't be instantiated?

Comment: The code provided doesn't make it explicit that `base` is abstract, but you are right, in which case the generic name `base_or_derived` could be renamed to `derived_from_base`. Thanks for the question! EDIT: the question explicitly mentions that `base` is ABC, so @24n8 is right.